# Possible reasons why PK index is correctly used in one environment, but is ignored in another. (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I'm investigating a performance issue with a query and I found out that it is not using an INDEX as we expected. It uses our index on the development server, but for some reason it doesn't in the production server. I have already checked that the index exists, and that the order is correct.

This is just a simplified version of the query: (it will probably work as expected on your PC, but it also failed on my co-worker's local environment)

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    a INT, b INT, c TEXT, d DATE, e TEXT, f INT, g INT, h INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
);
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY a, b, c;
```

Q: What would cause one database / environment to have different outcomes?

```
dev : Index Scan using t_pkey on t
prod: Sort Key a, b, c Sort Method: quicksort (on actual production it's external merge)
```

Settings / configuration? Number of records? Ownership? Postgresql version is the same (10.5).
Thanks!

Comment: You should have added the **complete** execution plans, but "*external merge*" indicates that there isn't enough `work_mem` to keep all rows in memory for sorting them. So the answer is likely: "settings and number of rows". But to be sure we need to see the execution plan from production generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers) ...`** - not just a simple `explain ...`. Please **[edit]** your question and add it as formatted text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: It does the same on SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5dc3f/1

Comment: The data are different on both systems. Try again after temporarily setting `enable_sort` to `off` and see if that makes the execution faster. If not, PostgreSQL was right.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: I understand the reason why external merge is used in production, it doesn't have enough memory for quicksort. I'm more interested in why it is sorting in the first place when a perfectly usable index (PK at that) is available. What's preventing the production environment from using the index scan? I'll try to see if I can get explain (analyze, buffers) from production.

Comment: @Laurentz Albe: I tried setting enable_sort to OFF on my co-worker's PC and it worked. I read the documentation, and it seems like a good idea to turn it off, but there must be a good reason why it is on by default. I won't be able to try this on the production server until I can provide evidence that it won't break things.

Comment: @Nick: I changed the data type of c from TEXT to INT on fiddle, and it worked. Date also works, Varchar doesn't.